# Using Rsync to copy folders/sub directories from specific date

Tags: rsync

```
I am using rsync to copy folders/ subdirectories from certain date and exclude all folders which is less than 180 days old.

My Folder Structure on Server1:


   ./BradsbarIN
     ./2016-06-01
              a.jpg
              b.jpg
              c.jpg
     ./2016-06-02
            a.jpg
            b.jpg
            c.jpg.
These dates go onto 2012-01-01. I want to rsync only last 180 days folders and exclude everything below from this date(2016-03-01).


rsync -avzn --list-only --include 'BradsbarIN/' --include 'BradsbarIN/2016-06-01/***' --exclude '*' -e ssh user@server.com:/path/to/old/data/ /path/to/new/data
```

I want to copy all the data in the folders from 2016-03-01 only. Is it possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
rsync -avzn \
      --list-only \
      --include 'BradsbarIN/' \
      --include 'BradsbarIN/2016-0[3-9]*/***' \
      --include 'BradsbarIN/2016-1*/***' \
      --include 'BradsbarIN/201[7-9]*/***' \
      --exclude '*' \
      -e ssh \
      user@server.com:/path/to/old/data/ \
      /path/to/new/data
```

I added the rules to make it continue to work for the next few months and years, but you only really need the first two include rules right now.